# Find the font from a single character

Tags: font-identification

I need to find the font from wich it was taken the F

[image: F glyph]

Comment: You can go to "What the Font" and upload an image of the character and usually it can find the exact font name for you. http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/

Comment: @Tracy: WhatTheFont is a great tool, but I do wish people recommending it on a specific font-identification question with a clear sample image would at least *try it* first. It shouldn't take too many seconds to paste the image URL from above into WhatTheFont and to observe that, no, in this case none of the returned matches are anywhere close to correct.

Answer (score 11):

It is [**Harlow Solid**](http://www.fonts.com/font/itc/harlow/solid), though it has been skewed/distorted:

[image: Harlow Solid Example]